# Is there a way to replace the for-each with apply-templates in an XSLT Transform?

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

**Environment:** XSLT 1.0
The transform will take each element in `partOne` section and lookup `@field` attribute in `partTwo` section using `@find` attribute and then output `@value` attribute.

I'm using a `for-each` loop and was wondering if `apply-templates` could work?

**xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="file.xslt"?>

<xml>
  <partOne>
    <target field="hello"/>
    <target field="world"/>
  </partOne>
  <partTwo>
    <number input="2" find="hello" value="valone" />
    <number input="2" find="world" value="valtwo"  />
    <number input="2" find="hello" value="valthree"  />
    <number input="2" find="world" value="valfour"  />    
  </partTwo>
</xml>
```

**xsl**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="text"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/xml/partOne/target">
    ,<xsl:value-of select="@field"/>

    <xsl:for-each select="/xml/partTwo/number[@find=current()/@field]">
      ,<xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
,hello
  ,valone
  ,valthree

,world
  ,valtwo
  ,valfour
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, it seems straight-forward to change

```
<xsl:for-each select="/xml/partTwo/number[@find=current()/@field]">
  ,<xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

to

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="/xml/partTwo/number[@find=current()/@field]"/>
```

with a template

```
<xsl:template match="partTwo/number">
      ,<xsl:value-of select="@value"/>
</xsl:template>
```

As your root template so far processes all elements you need to change it to

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="xml/partOne"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

to avoid processing the partTwo element(s) twice.

For the cross-reference you might want to use a key in both versions:

```
<xsl:key name="ref" match="partTwo/number" use="@find"/>
```

and then `select="key('ref', @field)"` instead of `select="/xml/partTwo/number[@find=current()/@field]"` for the `apply-templates` or `for-each`.

Comment: I get the desired output and then some...,valone,valtwo,valthree,valfour gets outputted as well, that part is not correct. Any ideas why it's doing that?

Comment: @Rod, see the edit, your current approach would process the partTwo twice, you would need to correct the apply-templates in the template matching `/`.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. However, I thought the `select` expression for `apply-templates` had to match exactly with `match` expression of the template?

Comment: It's the nodes selected by the select expression that have to match the `match` pattern in the template rules. For example nodes selected by `select="*"` can match a template rule with `match="para"`, while nodes selected by `select="para"` can match a rule with `match="*"`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen "For the cross-reference you might want to use a key in both versions."  What did you mean by this line?

Comment: @Rod, I have added an example of the `xsl:key`/`key` use.

Comment: Thanks so much for the insight (including you Mr. Kay, as always), this has been very educational! Several epiphany moments that I hope I can build from.